# Rails : which gem get priority?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am confuse that which gem will use by my application ? those gems which are stored in particular gemset or those which are store under vendor/bundle ?

let's discuss this scenario. First I did "bundle install - -path vendor/bundle" after this all gem is installed in vendor/bundle folder. Now changed my gemfile and delete .bundle folder. Creat new Gemset call mypro and use this gemset. Now I run "bundle install" and all gem installed under this Gemset. Now my question is when I run my application from which location gem is used?? From vender/bundle or from gemset

Comment: Those specified in your `Gemfile.lock`. If you don't use bundler, you should.

Comment: Okay, let's discuss this scenario. First I did "bundle install  - -path vendor/bundle"  after this all gem is installed in vendor/bundle folder. Now changed my gemfile and delete .bundle folder.   Creat new Gemset call mypro and use this gemset.  Now I run "bundle install"  and all gem installed under this Gemset.  Now my question is when I run my application from which location gem is used?? From vender/bundle or from gemset.

Comment: "from which location gem is used" - 1) why use gemsets with bundler? 2) it doesn't matter. The exact version specified in your Gemfile.lock will be loaded and it will be the same code in every location, unless you're editing code of the installed gems.

Comment: To answer your question exactly, I don't know. Never needed to find out.

Answer (score 0):

It will use your gemset even if you don't delete .bundle still it will use your new gemset